# Django database error: relation already exists

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
parent = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)

def clean(self):
    if self.name:
        if self.name == 'Minor Locality' and self.parent != 'City':
            raise ValidationError({
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["Parent tag can't be other City tag "]
        })
        if self.name == 'Locality' and self.parent != 'City':
            raise ValidationError({
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["Parent tag can't be other City tag "]
        })


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to add a tag 'City' and kept it's parent as blank, it throws an error on saving:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/locality/tag/add/

relation "locality_tag_parent" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "locality_tag_parent" WHERE ("locality_tag_paren...
```

Comment: Are you sure that `parent` should be a M2M relationship? Because if so, you really shouldn't be checking its status like you are in the `Clean` function.. Also, a `ManyToManyField` does not need `null` and `blank` attributes.

Comment: I have to put a check on this. That is necessary. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Something along the lines of `self.parent.filter(name='City').exists()`, I guess..